# File userform listboxes with values from sheet based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

VB noob. I am trying to fill userform list boxes with all times where the reservations column isn't blank, for each room. (If Reservations is blank, it's not a reservation made in advance).

Sample data:

```
date        room    intime      outime      Reservations
3/20/2017   5       10:00 AM    12:00 PM    Group1
3/20/2017   5       1:00 PM     2:00 PM     Group2
3/20/2017   3       11:00 PM    2:00 PM     Group2
3/20/2017   3       1:00 PM     2:00 PM     Group2
3/20/2017   4       10:25 AM
```

I have a listbox for each of the rooms. Here's my pseudocode:

```
Foreach row in range
If Reservations <>"" AND date = Date 'only want today's events
[write new statement combining intime and outtime values to display in the listbox in the userform]
```

Which looks like this:
[image: screenshot of userform in design mode]

So, I would like to have a userform populated when the workbook is opened to show that room 5 is booked from 10:00 AM to 12:00 AM and 1:00 PM to 2:00 PM, and that room 3 is booked from 11:00 AM to 12:00 AM and 1:00 PM to 2:00 PM.

So, a couple questions: 
Would my code end up in Workbook_Open() or UserForm_Initialize()?
How do you combine the two times into one statement?

Thanks

Comment: **1:** `UserForm_Initialize`. **2:** Use the string concatenation operator: `&`, e.g., `Range("C2").Text & " - " & Range("D2").Text` to display something like: `"10:00 AM - 12:00 PM"`

Comment: Thanks for the response and for the info.